# Adding XSL:Stylesheet If Then Else

Tags: xslt, attributes

I am trying to use the Choose, When and Otherwise statement for a query I am writing for LDAP in CCure ( Access Control System). TEXT18 value should be "Inactive". Text12 value should be "False". Otherwise pulls the data from the LDAP attribute and creates another column name "Disable". Hope this makes sense and thank you.

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<!-- Parameters assigned at runtime. -->
<xsl:param name="paramCurrentTimestamp">20001231173010</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="paramCurrentDT" >12/31/2000 5:30:10 PM</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="paramCurrentCulture">en-US</xsl:param>
<!-- The transformation below provides trivial default copy of everything. -->
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when Text18=”Inactive”><xsl:value-of select=”Inactive”/>.</xsl:when>
<xsl:when Text12=”False”><xsl:value-of select=”False”/>.</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise> "ucscPersonEmployeeStatus[text()='']">
<xsl:element name="Disabled">1</xsl:element>
<xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
<!-- End of customizable area. -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does not comprise a [mcve]. What is your sample input and your desired output?

Comment: Downvoting because it's a poor quesion. In fact, it's not a question at all. You've said you're trynig to use some particular constructs, but you haven't said what you're trying to achieve (convert input X to output Y), and you haven't said how your current attempt is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the `</xsl:otherwise>` and the `</xsl:choose>` elements. Fixing these stylesheets issues, the following may work for you:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <!-- Parameters assigned at runtime. -->
    <xsl:param name="paramCurrentTimestamp">20001231173010</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="paramCurrentDT" >12/31/2000 5:30:10 PM</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="paramCurrentCulture">en-US</xsl:param>
    <!-- The transformation below provides trivial default copy of everything. -->
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when Text18="Inactive">
                <xsl:value-of select="Inactive"/>
            .</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when Text12="False">
                <xsl:value-of select="False"/>
            .</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise> "ucscPersonEmployeeStatus[text()='']">
                <xsl:element name="Disabled">1</xsl:element>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- End of customizable area. -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry my question, but, the "test" attribute is not necessary?

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for taking the time on my novice approach on creating my first xlst script for our access database. Although, I was not completely clear, most of you figured it out. Thanks again. I found out a few more things today about the script source. Text18 does have a value of Inactive. Text 12 has a value of null/blank to capture. Is there another way to capture the null value? Also, the element name =Disable, creates a column name with information to be inputted into a reference column name Status.  Hope this clears up some of your questions. Stay Safe!

Comment: Glad that some of my/our guessings were of some help to you. Next time, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question. Then my/our help would probably be more fruitful.

Comment: Still having a problem with Text12 capturing an empty field/value.Null values does not work with this LDAP system. Any ideas please? How do I rewrite it? Thank you

Comment: You should really have a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), rethink the whole topic and then ask a well designed new question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two template rules that match attributes (`@*`) and that do different things. The first one (with `match="*|@*"`) doesn't look as if it was designed to handle attributes.

When the entire body of a template rules consists of an xsl:choose, it's often better to split it into multiple template rules, for example

```
<xsl:template match="*[Text18='Inactive']">
      <xsl:value-of select="`Inactive`"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[Text12='False']">
      <xsl:value-of select="`False`"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm guessing here that you want to output the literal strings "Inactive" and "False" rather than the content of elements named "Inactive" and "False", but with no information about your input and desired output, this can only be a guess.